# mongodb time duration between between two dates

Tags: mongodb

I want to find the time duration in the form of days:hours:minutes by passing two dates in mongodb for all document.

Example document present in mongodb:

```
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b3b303f4a05d1673d9bfa31"),
      "customerID" : "1",
      "latitude" : "13.035770",
      "longitude" : "77.597022",
      "loc_update_time" : 1533021761818.0,
      "loc" : [ 
         77.597022, 
         13.03577
       ],
       "datetime" : ISODate("2018-08-01T09:43:25.729Z")
    }
```

one date is present in douctment and another date i will pass in query.
please help me
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to do this from mongo shell or a client? if a client, what driver are you using?

Comment: i am using robo 3t

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: i tried below code it is filtering the douctments.But i required time duration between these two dates

Comment: db.Customer.aggregate([
   { "$redact": {
       "$cond": {
           "if": {
               "$gt": [
                   { "$subtract": [ new Date(), "$datetime" ] },
                   1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
               ]
           },
           "then": "$$KEEP",
           "else": "$$PRUNE"
       }
   }}
])